# Exporting cloud masked images from MODIS EVI collection as separate images

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am performing cloud masking on a collection of modis images.The code below  works on the cloud masking part however when i export the images it brings the error below    [image: the error that is returned].I do not know what is the problem causing the error.

```
var maskEmptyPixels = function(image) {
      var withObs = image.select('EVI').gt(0);
      return image.updateMask(withObs); 
      };
    var maskClouds = function(image) {
      var QA = image.select('SummaryQA');
      var bitMask = 1 << 10;
      return image.updateMask(QA.bitwiseAnd(bitMask).eq(0));
    }; 
    var table_bounds = function(image){
     return image.clip(table); 
    };
    var collection =ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1' )
                   .filterDate('2019-03-01', '2019-07-30')
                    .filterBounds(table).select('EVI','SummaryQA')
                    .map(maskEmptyPixels);
    var evicollection = collection.map(table_bounds);
    var totalObsCount = evicollection
            .select('EVI')
            .count();
    var collectionCloudMasked = evicollection.map(maskClouds);
    var clearObsCount = collectionCloudMasked
            .select('EVI')
            .count()
            .unmask(0);
    Map.setCenter(35.94,-0.37,8);
    Map.addLayer(
        collectionCloudMasked.median(),
        {bands: ['EVI'],
         gain: 0.07,
         gamma: 1.4
        },
        'median of masked collection'
      );
      print(collectionCloudMasked);
    var list = collectionCloudMasked.toList(11);
    for(var i=1;i<11;i++){
      var nam=ee.String('EVI_img')
                 .cat(ee.String(ee.Number(i)))
                 .getInfo();
    }
    Export.image.toDrive({   
           image: collectionCloudMasked,
           description: nam,
           scale:250,
           maxPixels:1e13
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Currently, this is an example of a "Wall of code" question, which tend to be down-voted and/or ignored. Please [Edit] the question to contain a paragraph or two describing your environment, software, data, procedure, and error message(s) (which should be in text, to be searchable). The title should be a summary of the issue, not the only description of what you are attempting.

Comment: 'median of masked collection'.toList(11) doesn't work. 'median of masked collection' is a string, which doesn't have a toList() method. You probably wanted to invoke toList() on one of your image collections. It's hard for me to tell what you are trying to do, but maybe you wanted collectionCloudMasked.toList(11)?

Comment: Since cloud masking leaves gaps,,I wanted to use median () to fill the gaps,such that the image collections that I export has median performed on them

Comment: You are trying to export an entire collection, you are supposed to export one image only, or perhaps you can do a for loop to export all the imaged in the collection